# How to use the 'export' command in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

If I run the below command directly in terminal, `kubectl` is getting enabled. If I use the same command with shell module in Ansible playbook, its executing but its not doing its job of enabling the `kubectl`.

```bash
export KUBECONFIG="/etc/rancher/rke2/rke2.yaml" \
&& export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/var/lib/rancher/rke2/bin"
```

Ansible playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Copy installer
  hosts: FIRST_SERVER
  gather_facts: yes
  ignore_unreachable: true
  any_errors_fatal: true
  tasks:
    - name: Execute enable kubectl on primary server
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['FIRST_SERVER']
      shell: |
        set -o pipefail
        export KUBECONFIG="/etc/rancher/rke2/rke2.yaml"
        export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/var/lib/rancher/rke2/bin"
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
      become: yes
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You are exporting environment variables in a shell on the remote target which will die as soon your task is over (as when you close your terminal after typing those manually). Basically your above example is syntactically correct but does absolutely nothing. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I added the kubectl command in the same task and registered the output. It worked. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is [setting remote environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) variables for the task temporary only.

For certain servers I am the following approach of

- [What do the scripts in `/etc/profile.d` do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64258/)

by using

```yaml
- name: Provide environment variable script file
  template:
    src: "{{ item }}.j2"
    dest: "/etc/profile.d/{{ item }}"
  with_items:
     - "environment.sh"
```

and in example

```
# /etc/profile.d/environment.sh

export ACCOUNT=$(who am i | cut -d " " -f 1)
export DOMAIN=$(hostname | cut -d "." -f 2-4)
```

**Further Q&A**

- ["*Scripts placed in ... get sourced on login*"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451513/266568)
- [How to set an environment variable during package installation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490428/266568)

By doing this I am able to set persistent environment variables for specific software and services.